# How do I customize my desktop to look like this screenshot?

Tags: customization

So I've come back to linux because I've fallen back in love with the command line (albeit I'm not so great with it) and the customability of linux based OS's. My question really comes from not knowing how to customize certain aspects of the OS.

To begin with, I want it to look like this.
[image]
I have only gotten it to work like this.
[image]

So I'm running the cairo-dock with unity bar. But a couple of annoyances. I don't know how to get that little window thing to go away on the lower left corener. It allows you to switch between the four workspaces, but doesn't look as clean. Secondly,my "Top bar" doesn't look like the one I want to replicate, because I don't know where to begin. Any solutions for my two problems?

### Update #1:

Installing Gnome 3 seemed to give me a bar on top that looks closer to the outcome, but it doesn't work with cairo.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also, the icon theme in the top picture is Faenza.

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

Then choose your icon theme using eg. Ubuntu Tweak:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: The only thing that did not work was your last line `sudo apt-get install ubuntu tweak` Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't remember anymore whether Ubuntu Tweak was in the repositories or not. Doesn't seem to be. Therefore do a "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next" in terminal, then "sudo apt-get update", then "sudo apt-get install ubuntu tweak". (from here: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/source/tualatrix-next/). Good luck

Comment: Maybe better: "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa" (stable PPA)

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot above probably shows the Gnome3 shell, not Unity.
Here is the command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-theme-standard gnome-tweak-tool gnome-contacts gnome-sushi dconf-tools
```

After that just choose *Gnome* when logging in.
It might help with your other problem as well.

Comment: "Unable to locate package gnome-theme-standard"

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-themes-standard gnome-tweak-tool gnome-contacts gnome-sushi dconf-tools` instead. There was a s missing.

Comment: Check Update #1

Comment: I am not too much into Cairo dock, but you might get help from this article.
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/cairo-dock-30-released-with-gtk3.html